# Why is there no option selected in the drop down list?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, drop-down-menu, selectlist

I'm confused as to why the corresponding option in the select list is not being selected.
When I step through the loop, `item.DisciplineId = 2`, but School is not selected ("Choose" still is). Any suggestions ?

**View**

```
<% foreach (var item in Model.TeamMembers)
{ %>
<tr>
    <td>
        <%: Html.DropDownListFor(m => item.DisciplineId, Model.MemberDisciplines, "Choose") %>
    </td>
</tr>
<% } %>
```

**View Model**

```
public SelectList MemberDisciplines { get; set; }
public IEnumerable<TeamMember> TeamMembers { get; set; }//Set from the model

MemberDisciplines = new SelectList(new[] {
                new SelectListItem{ Text = "Technical", Value = "1"},
                new SelectListItem{ Text = "School", Value = "2"},
                new SelectListItem{ Text = "Health", Value = "3"}
            }, "Value", "Text");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, I would then suggest you to convert MemberDisciplines property into a method with the following content:

```
public SelectList GetMemberDisciplines(object selectedValue)
{
    return new SelectList(new[] {
        new SelectListItem{ Text = "Technical", Value = "1"},
        new SelectListItem{ Text = "School", Value = "2"},
        new SelectListItem{ Text = "Health", Value = "3"}
    }, "Value", "Text", selectedValue);
}
```

And then you call it in your DropDownListFor like so:

```
<% for (int i = 0; i < Model.TeamMembers.Count; i++) { %>
  <tr>
      <td>
          <%: Html.DropDownListFor(m => Model.TeamMembers[i].DisciplineId, Model.GetMemberDisciplines(Model.TeamMembers[i].DisciplineId), "Choose..")%>
      </td>
  </tr>
<% } %>
```

Comment: I wish it was that. Sorry for being a little confusing (I updated the code), but I am definitely getting the `DisciplineId` which is a simple `string` variable.

Comment: Updated the answer.. hope it helps.

Comment: Works perfectly, wish I knew why it wasn't happy the other way though. I didn't even think of making a method, I'll have to keep that in mind. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I realized that the previous example gives you the same ID "item_DisciplineId" for all drop-lists so it can't be used for POST scenario b/c TeamMembers doesn't get automatically populated - please consider using the revised version. BTW - you can also go further and implement Html.EditorFor with a templated view but that's another story.